# Kubernetes: How to collect stdout/stderr logs using sidecar container

Tags: logging, kubernetes, sidecar

There is a container which print logs to stdout/stderr, and I have no access to host machines, so can not use node log collector to collect and send them to a central logging system(ElasticSearch here), is there a way to use a sidecar container to do such thing?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [fluentbit](https://fluentbit.io) as a sidecar to send logs to Elasticsearch. There is no process that you need to run in the host for this. Below is an example yaml.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    name: fluentbit-logging-sidecar
  spec:
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: fluentbit-logging-sidecar
    replicas: 1
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app: fluentbit-logging-sidecar
        volumes:
          - name: shared-data
            emptyDir: {}
          - name: config-volume
            configMap:
              name: fb-agent-config
        containers:
          - name: sample-logging
            image: <image>
            volumeMounts:
            - name: shared-data
              mountPath: /app/logs
          - name: fb-sidecar
            image: fluent/fluent-bit  
            volumeMounts:
            - name: shared-data
              mountPath: /app/logs
            - name: config-volume
              mountPath: /fluent-bit/etc/fluent-bit.conf
              subPath: fluent-bit.conf
```

You need to configure your application to write log in filesystem in the path `/app/logs`. Because the app container and fluentbit container share the path using `volumeMounts` fluentbit sidecar will be able to read logs from that path and stream it to Elasticsearch. You need to configure [details of elastic search](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/outputs/elasticsearch) in `fluent-bit.conf` file.

Comment: is it possible to not modify app to write log to filesystem but just get log from stdout directly?

Comment: Looking at input plugins fluentbit supports it's not possible https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/inputs